# Eclipse: When displaying a list of methods (ctrl-space), is there a way to have methods in that class - bold?

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse:

When displaying a list of methods (ctrl-space), is there a way to have methods found in that class have names in bold? Netbeans has or at least had a feature that would bold the names of methods found within that class while inherited methods remained normal text.

This made it very easy to know what methods are from within the class you are editing.

Is there a way to do this in the latest version of Eclipse?

Thanks.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't have this function, but you can see from where the method came at the right side of the return type.

Comment: @JorgeCampos - as you say, you 'can' determine this information but once you've gotten used to having method names in bold and the ease of use that provides... it is a feature sorely missed. I hope that someone has made a plug-in for this feature.

Comment: IntelliJ does that too. and it sorts methods from sub class to base class

Comment: Why am I using Eclipse?? Oh right, because netbeans does not make it easy to integrate Perforce support. /sigh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems eclipse does not support it.

What I do in such cases (workaround):

- Open the affected class (`Navigate` -> `Open Type...`)
- Press CTRL-O, this will show the methods implemented in this class.
- Press CTRL-O again, this will also show the inherited methods.

Comment: Thanks for the information. When I am done giving the beta of IntelliJ IDEA a test run I'll try out your advice.

Comment: Actually this is a great tip. I was aware of Ctrl + O, but never knew about pressing it again to show inherited methods. Nice +1